# Google maps currently loads only places based on a static address

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Th following code works correctly, however the 'start' value is coming form the data-start attribute assigned to the div containing the map.

I need the following to accept the current coordinates of the current location (from the geolocation code):

```
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ address: **start** }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                opts.center = results[0].geometry.location;
                self.map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], opts);
                $.post($('#stockists form').attr('action'), { query: start }, function(data) {
                    self.addMarkers(data.results);
                });
                self.locateUser();
            } else {
                alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
        });
```

The start value suppose to take the current location instead of the static value coming from the data attribute. You can see the full code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xCUrh/1/)

The idea is to load data.results based on your current location.....

Comment: Let me know if you guys need this to be more clear...

Comment: Can we have an example with an actual google maps ? Not sure if you can set that up on jsFiddle though

Comment: I have the added more code here for a better idea.. http://jsfiddle.net/xCUrh/4/

Comment: I think it's a matter of getting the coordinates from the geolocation ans pass them in the post function..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current location(of the user) can be detected by using [geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_geolocation).

So the steps:

1. detect the location of the user
2. request the formatted_address  by using [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding)
3. set `$('#map').data('start')` to the result of the reverse-geocoding
4. create a new Map-object and call the init-method: `new Map().init();`

Example:

```
  var geocoder=new google.maps.Geocoder();
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    geocoder.geocode({latLng:new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
                                                    position.coords.longitude)},
          function(results,status){
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              $('#map').data('start',results[0].formatted_address);
              new Map().init();
          }
        })
  });
```

Comment: Hi geolocation is already in place and it works fine, I ams struggling to revert the geolocation coordinates and update $('#map').data('start')

Comment: for reverse geocoding the geocoder expects a latLng-parameter, which must contain a google.maps.LatLng-object. I added an example.

Comment: OK I have changed my code but now I get 'setCenter' undefined. http://jsfiddle.net/xCUrh/5/

Comment: you can't use a method  of the map before the map is created. However, there is no need to set the center of the map (also the call of locateUser is unnecessary), because you already set the center of the map with `opts.center`

Comment: Ok it's now sorted, I had to use geocoder to revert the coordinates coming from the geolocation use a new post function withing the geolocation code..